# Python/Plotly Offline export result into Image instead of html file

Tags: python, plotly, offline

How can I export offline my PLOTLY results into **Image** (png, jpeg, jpg) or **pdf** instead of html format?

```
filename="test.html"
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename=filename,show_link=False,auto_open=False)
```

If there is no direct solution, How can i convert this html plotly result into ppt/pdf/image later on ?

Comment: Have a look into plotly orca.  This is the graphing engine behind plotly and can export to PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [static export](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) using the following:

```
fig.write_image("my_fig.png")
```